# PHP form error somwhere $_POST['SUBMIT']

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, debugging

I do not know where is the problem, can you help me? I can not debug this. 
I tried to put an echo everywhere to see where is the problem and it stopped at `if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])) {`

Here is the whole php:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect($IP, "pavip", "", "c9") or die("Kapcsolatot nem sikerult letrehozni!");

$error = "Here's the problem: ";
$err = false;
$name = $_POST['name'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])) {
    echo $name;
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        if($_POST['name'] != "") {
            if($_POST['pass'] == $_POST['pass2'] AND strlen($_POST['pass']) < 6) {
                if($_POST['email'] != "") {

                    $name = $_POST['name'];
                    $password = $_POST['pass'];
                    $email = $_POST['email'];

                    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, password, email)
                    VALUES ('$name, '$password','$email)";
                }else {
                    $error .= "No email";
                    $err = true;
                }
            }else {
                $error .= "Password too short or wrong ujrairas ";
                $err = true;
            }
        }else {
            $error .= "No name ";
            $err = true;
        }
    }else {

    }
}
if($err == true){ echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $error . '"); </script>';}
?>
```

And here is the form I made:

```
<form action="index.php" method="Post" class="register">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name(Can be nick!)">
                <input type="pasword" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Password again">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                <input type="submit" value="Register">
            </form>
```

Comment: `name attribute` missing in submit type!! add `name="SUBMIT"` in submit button

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you! @djot :I didn't know what is it in english so I wrote in hungarian :)

Comment: You have issues with your code login as well. You process the form if the password is less than 6 characters. It looks like you are using plain text passwords. You also are open to sql injections.

Comment: I just wanted to make a demo @chris85 I wanted to write something that writes something to somewhere. But now I have problem with mysql so it have a lot of bugs how I see.

Comment: This is an error, `'$name,` it is missing the closing quote in the SQL. If values contain a quote this will also break..

Comment: This isn't live or intended to go live I hope.

Comment: @pavip making a "demo" not conforming to best practices is not a good things to do... Usually these issues are users updating old code; if just starting you should start out on the right path..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `$_POST['SUBMIT']` is not found as your form does not have a `name` attribute.

You'll need to specify it:

```
<input name="SUBMIT" type="submit" value="Register"/>
```

---

Secondly, you'll missed out a single quote at `'$email`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, password, email)
                VALUES ('$name, '$password','$email')";
```

---

Thirdly, you should prevent MySQL Injection using `mysqli_real_escape_string`:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pass']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
```

---

Fourthly, you can consider using `empty()` to check for empty fields, e.g.:

```
if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @luweiqi

Comment: @pavip You're welcome! Glad to have solved your problem :)

Comment: But I have to learn more about security. I donot even know why I need mysql connection and etc.. Thanks again! :) @luweiqi

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look that you don't have input name="SUBMIT" mentioned anywhere in your HTML.

Change your:

```
<input type="submit" value="Register">
```

To

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="SUBMIT" />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

you do not have an submit button named "SUBMIT"
if you want to use it this way you need to add atleast

```
<input type="submit" name="SUBMIT">
```

it would be better to directly route the submit to a different controller function to
note that you can also use if($_POST) afaik